# How to fix "Template parse errors " in Angularjs version 7

Tags: angularjs

I was trying to use animation together with a progress spinner on feedback form of contact page of my project and using the post() method to return the submitted feedback object as a return value to display briefly the submitted data to confirm the form submission to the user:

```
    enter code here// code for contact.component.ts
       import { FeedbackService } from './../services/feedback.service';
       import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild, Inject } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { Feedback, ContactType } from '../shared/feedback';
import { flyInOut, expand } from '../animations/app.animation';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-contact',
  templateUrl: './contact.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./contact.component.scss'],
  // tslint:disable-next-line:use-host-property-decorator
  host: {
    '[@flyInOut]': 'true',
    'style': 'display: block;'
    },
  animations: [
    flyInOut(),
    expand()
  ]
})
export class ContactComponent implements OnInit {
  @ViewChild('fform') feedbackFormDirective;
  submitted: boolean;
  feedbackForm: FormGroup;
  feedback: Feedback;
  contactType = ContactType;
  errMess: string;
  formErrors = {
    'firstname': '',
    'lastname': '',
    'telnum': '',
    'email': ''
  };

  validationMessages = {
    'firstname': {
      'required':      'First Name is required.',
      'minlength':     'First Name must be at least 2 characters long.',
      'maxlength':     'FirstName cannot be more than 25 characters long.'
    },
    'lastname': {
      'required':      'Last Name is required.',
      'minlength':     'Last Name must be at least 2 characters long.',
      'maxlength':     'Last Name cannot be more than 25 characters long.'
    },
    'telnum': {
      'required':      'Tel. number is required.',
      'pattern':       'Tel. number must contain only numbers.'
    },
    'email': {
      'required':      'Email is required.',
      'email':         'Email not in valid format.'
    },
  };
  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder,
    private feedbackService: FeedbackService,
    @Inject('BaseURL') public BaseURL) {
    this.createForm();
   }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  createForm() {
    this.feedbackForm = this.fb.group({
      firstname: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(2), Validators.maxLength(25)] ],
      lastname: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(2), Validators.maxLength(25)] ],
      telnum: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.pattern] ],
      email: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.email] ],
      agree: false,
      contacttype: 'None',
      message: ''
    });
    this.feedbackForm.valueChanges
      .subscribe(data => this.onValueChanged(data));

    this.onValueChanged(); // (re)set validation messages now
  }

  onValueChanged(data?: any) {
    if (!this.feedbackForm) { return; }
    const form = this.feedbackForm;
    for (const field in this.formErrors) {
      if (this.formErrors.hasOwnProperty(field)) {
        // clear previous error message (if any)
        this.formErrors[field] = '';
        const control = form.get(field);
        if (control && control.dirty && !control.valid) {
          const messages = this.validationMessages[field];
          for (const key in control.errors) {
            if (control.errors.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
              this.formErrors[field] += messages[key] + ' ';
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }

  onSubmit() {
    this.submitted = true;
    this.feedback = this.feedbackForm.value;
    console.log(this.feedback);
    this.feedbackService.submitFeedback(this.feedback)
      .subscribe(data => {
        this.feedback = data,
        // after 5s form becomes not submitted (visible)
        setTimeout(() => {
          this.submitted = false; }, 5000); },
      errmess => { this.feedback = null; this.errMess = <any>errmess; });
      this.feedbackFormDirective.resetForm();
    this.feedbackForm.reset({
      firstname: '',
      lastname: '',
      telnum: '',
      email: '',
      agree: false,
      contacttype: 'None',
      message: ''
    });
  }
}
 // code of contact.component.html
     <div class="container"
  fxLayout="column"
  fxLayoutGap="10px">

  <div fxFlex>
    <div>
        <h3>Contact Us</h3>
        <hr>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div fxFlex>
    <h3>Location Information</h3> 
    <div fxLayout="column" fxLayout.gt-sm="row">
      <div fxFlex="50" fxFlexOffset="20px">
        <h4>Our Address</h4>
        <address>
          121, Clear Water Bay Road<br>
          Clear Water Bay, Kowloon<br>
          HONG KONG<br>
          <i class="fa fa-phone"></i>: +852 1234 5678<br>
          <i class="fa fa-fax"></i>: +852 8765 4321<br>
          <i class="fa fa-envelope"></i>: 
                <a href="mailto:confusion@food.net">confusion@food.net</a>
        </address>
        <p></p>
        <div>
          <a mat-raised-button href="tel:+85212345678"><i class="fa fa-phone"></i> Call</a>
          <a mat-raised-button><i class="fa fa-skype"></i> Skype</a>
          <a mat-raised-button href="mailto:confusion@food.net"><i class="fa fa-envelope-o"></i> Email</a>
        </div>
        </div>
      <div fxFlex="40">
        <h4>Map of our Location</h4>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div fxFlex fxFlexOffset="20px" class="form-size">
      <h3>Send us your Feedback</h3>
      <p>{{ feedbackForm.value | json }} {{ feedbackForm.status | json }}</p>



    <form novalidate [formGroup]="feedbackForm" #fform="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
      <p>
          <mat-form-field class="half-width">
              <input matInput formControlName="firstname" placeholder="First Name" type="text" required>
              <mat-error *ngIf="formErrors.firstname">{{formErrors.firstname}}</mat-error>
            </mat-form-field>
            <mat-form-field class="half-width">
              <input matInput formControlName="lastname" placeholder="Last Name" type="text" required>
              <mat-error *ngIf="formErrors.lastname">{{formErrors.lastname}}</mat-error>
            </mat-form-field>
          </p>
          <p>
            <mat-form-field class="half-width">
              <input matInput formControlName="telnum" placeholder="Tel. Number" type="tel" pattern="[0-9]*" required>
              <mat-error *ngIf="formErrors.telnum">{{formErrors.telnum}}</mat-error>
            </mat-form-field>
            <mat-form-field class="half-width">
              <input matInput formControlName="email" placeholder="Email" type="email" email required>
              <mat-error *ngIf="formErrors.email">{{formErrors.email}}</mat-error>
            </mat-form-field>
      </p>


        <table class="form-size">
          <td>
            <mat-slide-toggle formControlName="agree">May we contact you?</mat-slide-toggle>
          </td>
          <td>
            <mat-select placeholder="HowS?" formControlName="contacttype">
              <mat-option *ngFor="let ctype of contactType" [value]="ctype">
                {{ ctype }}
              </mat-option>
            </mat-select>
          </td>
          </table>
        <p>
          <mat-form-field class="full-width">
            <textarea matInput formControlName="message" placeholder="Your Feedback" rows=12></textarea>
          </mat-form-field>
        </p>
        <button type="submit" mat-button class="background-primary text-floral-white">Submit</button>
      </form>


  </div>

  <div [hidden]="feedback || errMess">

    <mat-spinner></mat-spinner>
  </div>
  <div fxflex  *ngif="feedback && submitted" @expand]=" ">   
    <mat-list >
      <h3>Your Submission</h3>
      <mat-list-item>
        <p matline="">First Name: {{feedback.firstname}} </p>
        <p matline="">Last Name: {{feedback.lastname}} </p>
        <p matline="">Tel. Number: {{feedback.telnum}}</p>
        <p matline="">Email: {{feedback.email}}</p>
        <p matline="">Contact You?: {{feedback.agree}}</p>
        <p matline="">How?: {{feedback.contacttype}}</p>
        <p matline="">Feedback: {{feedback.message}}</p>
      </mat-list-item>
    </mat-list>
  </div>
</div>

 // feedback.service.ts
    import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { Feedback,ContactType } from '../shared/feedback';
import { map, catchError } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { ProcessHTTPMsgService } from './process-httpmsg.service';
import { baseURL } from '../shared/baseurl';
import { HttpClient, HttpErrorResponse, HttpHeaders,HttpSentEvent } from '@angular/common/http';

const HttpUploadOptions = {
  headers: new HttpHeaders({ "Content-Type": "application/json"  })
}
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class FeedbackService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient, private processHTTPMsgService: ProcessHTTPMsgService) { }
  submitFeedback(feedback : Feedback):Observable<Feedback>{
    return this.http.post<Feedback>((baseURL + 'feedback'), feedback, HttpUploadOptions)
    .pipe(
      catchError(this.processHTTPMsgService.handleError)   
       );



  }
}
 // app.animation.ts

      import { trigger, state, style, animate, transition } from '@angular/animations';

export function visibility() {
    return trigger('visibility', [
        state('shown', style({
            transform: 'scale(1.0)',
            opacity: 1
        })),
        state('hidden', style({
            transform: 'scale(0.5)',
            opacity: 0
        })),
        transition('* => *', animate('0.5s ease-in-out'))
    ]);
}
export function flyInOut() {
    return trigger('flyInOut', [
        state('*', style({ opacity: 1, transform: 'translateX(0)'})),
        transition(':enter', [
            style({ transform: 'translateX(-100%)', opacity: 0 }),
            animate('500ms ease-in')
        ]),
        transition(':leave', [
            animate('500ms ease-out', style({ transform: 'translateX(100%)', opacity: 0}))
        ])
    ]);
}

export function expand() {
    return trigger('expand', [
        state('*', style({ opacity: 1, transform: 'translateX(0)' })),
        transition(':enter', [
            style({ transform: 'translateY(-50%)', opacity:0 }),
            animate('200ms ease-in', style({ opacity: 1, transform: 'translateX(0)' }))
        ])
    ]);
}
```

I was actually doing task 4 of angularjs assignment on an online portal and the details are --
    Task 4
 In this task you will use animation together with a progress spinner and the fact that the post() method will return the submitted feedback object as a return value to display briefly the submitted data to confirm the form submission to the user:

When the form is submitted, you should hide the form and display the progress spinner until the server responds confirming the update on the server side. See the next point below for further details.
Recall how in the lesson on saving data to the server, the PUT request returns an observable that we subscribe and then use the updated dish data returned to update the dish object in dishdetail.component.ts. Similarly when you do a post(), the feedback service must return the feedback object returned from the server after submission, by the submitFeedback() method. You can then subscribe to it within the contact.component.ts to obtain the returned feedback object. This confirms the successful submission of the feedback to the server.
After obtaining the confirmation from the server within the subscribe() method above, you should then display the information from the returned feedback object in the format as shown in the video for 5 seconds. Thereafter you should hide this and then again show the empty form to the user enabling them to submit the feedback again. Hint: Leverage the setTimeout() method for this purpose.
Use the expand animation that we have already used earlier to judiciously apply animation to the various stages of the form submission.

Comment: Angularjs is the term used for Angular version 1. So there is no Angularjs version 7. But there is an "Angular 7"